# Number of decimal with select_avg() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, average

Is there any way to show only one decimal using `select_avg()` in CodeIgniter?

```
 $this->db  
      ->select_avg('Stars')
      ->from('Reviews') 
      $query=$this->db->get();  
      return $query->result();
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Check answer below

Comment: Could [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) help in controller or view?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$this->db->select_avg(ROUND('Nr_stele'))->from('Recenzii as r');
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

> Check [SQL `ROUND()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp) and [`$this->db->select_avg()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=$this-%3Edb-%3Eselect_avg()) in codeigniter

Comment: I don't want ROUND, I just want it to be 4.5 not  4.5000